# Does anyone know how to implement a search bar that has tabs like that of instagram using flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-plugin, flutter-appbar, flutter-image

Does anyone know how to implement a search bar such as this one?

[image]

[image]